# Scala accessing variable outside function

Tags: scala, closures

I was reading an article at https://medium.com/@aarshkshah1992/scala-functional-memoization-and-lazy-loading-caches-de116f24828

and this part is really interesting

```
def memoizedIsPrime: Int => Boolean = {
  def checkIfPrime(i: Int): Boolean = {
    2 to (i - 1) forall (x => i % x != 0)
  }

  var cache = Map.empty[Int, Boolean]
  i => {
    if (!cache.contains(i)) {
      print(s"Calling isPrime since input ${i} has not been seen before and caching the output")
      cache = cache updated(i, checkIfPrime(i))
    }
    else print(s"Input ${i} has been seen before , returning cached output")
    cache(i)
  }
}

val isPrime = memoizedIsPrime
```

Can anyone explain how i is being accessed and the how the code part after => is really working?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `memoizedIsPrime` is `Int => Boolean`, in other words a function that takes an `Int` and returns a `Boolean`.

So in the body of the code, after we get some preliminary `def` and `val` definitions out of the way, we need a way to reference the incoming `Int`:

```
i => ...
```

OK, so it is decided, we'll refer to the received `Int` as `i`. Now we need to produce a `Boolean` value. And that, of course, is the `{` `}` delimited block of code that comes after the `=>` which gets executed every time a new `Int` arrives.

Comment: What if memoizedIsPrime took multiple parameters? would it be (i, j)?

Comment: A memoized function of arity 2 would create a 2-tuple with the received parameter values and use that tuple as the key to the cache lookup.

Comment: Tried. Thanks :)